# Echo behaviour of Microsoft Windows Telnet Client

Tags: windows, client, telnet, behavior

When using the Microsoft Telnet Client, the first message isn't echoed locally, but subsequent messages are.

Why is that the case? Is this documented somewhere?

Are there other quirks of the Microsoft implementation?
Are they documented somewhere?

(This question is about "a specific programming problem", because a specific server implementation should get the Microsoft Telnet Client to echo the first message.)